# How to Compare LONG Data Type with CLOB

Tags: sql, oracle, long-integer, clob, ora-00932

I want to compare the `text(LONG)` FROM `user_views` dictionary view in oracle with `text(CLOB)` in user created table `all_views_backup`.

Something like :

```
CREATE TABLE all_views_backup AS 
SELECT view_name, text_length, to_lob(text) AS text 
  FROM user_views;

SELECT dbms_lob.compare(to_lob(uv.text),avb.text)
  FROM all_views_backup avb
  JOIN user_views uv
    ON avb.view_name = uv.view_name;
```

table created succesfully.

The result should be 1 for difference in text and 0 for same,
but in query I got the error

> ```
> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got LONG.
> ```

Help me with that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To work with LONGs, you are going to need PL/SQL. This will get a LONG column value into a CLOB:

```
DECLARE
  var_clob clob;
BEGIN
  FOR rec_view IN (SELECT * FROM all_views)
  LOOP
     var_clob := rec_view.text;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

You can then use all the string manipulation and/or comparison operators/functions you want against the CLOB. On this basis you can write the code to do the comparison you are trying to do. This is the easiest method.

If you want to create a *view* over the top of `all_views` that presents `all_views` content but with a `TEXT` field of CLOB rather than LONG, you'll need `dbms_sql` to do that. For the conversion of the LONG to CLOB in that context, you can use `dbms_lob.createtemporary`, loop on `dbms_sql.column_value_long` and append content to the temporary CLOB using `dbms_lob.append`. Here's an excerpt from my `dba_views` overlay view that does exactly that. As an excerpt, it can't be used as-is but is part of a much larger function that manipulates `dbms_sql`, but it at least gives you the concept:

```
DECLARE
  var_text_clob clob;
  var_offset pls_integer := 0;
  var_buffer_length pls_integer := 32760;
  var_value_length pls_integer := 0;
  var_long_piece long;
BEGIN
  dbms_lob.createtemporary(var_text_clob, false, dbms_lob.call);
    
  LOOP
    dbms_sql.column_value_long(c => var_cursor,
                               position => 4,
                               length => var_buffer_length,
                               offset => var_offset,
                               value => var_long_piece,
                               value_length => var_value_length);
                               
    EXIT WHEN var_value_length = 0;
    
    dbms_lob.append(var_text_clob, var_long_piece);
    var_offset := var_offset + var_value_length;
  END LOOP;
  
  rec_view.text := var_text_clob;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks, Using a CLOB variable in PL/SQL Block works perfectly fine.